# Can't use psych::describe with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, psych

I noticed a strange error in which certain dplyr verbs (in this case, `select`) are throwing errors when used in conjunction with `psych::describe` even if `mutate` is not:  Example:

OK:

```
psych::describe(mtcars$mpg) %>% 
    mutate(variance = var(mtcars$mpg))
```

Not OK

```
psych::describe(mtcars$mpg) %>% 
    mutate(variance = var(mtcars$mpg)) %>%
    select(n, mean, sd, variance, skew, kurtosis)
```

Error:

```
Error: Can't reconstruct data frame.
x The `[` method for class <psych/describe/data.frame> must return a data frame.
i It returned a <describe>.
```

I recall that this worked previously, or perhaps I am imagining it. **What is the workaround?**

Note that I can save `describe(mtcars$mpg)` assign this to an object `x` and run `class(x)`, I get:

`[1] "psych"      "describe"   "data.frame"`

---

Based on comments below, I realize this does not happen every time. Here is my session info for a **FRESH** R Session, where the error did not occur:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.5.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.0    
[4] purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.1.0    
[7] tibble_3.0.1    ggplot2_3.3.1   tidyverse_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.1.0 xfun_0.14        haven_2.3.1     
 [4] lattice_0.20-41  colorspace_1.4-1 vctrs_0.3.0     
 [7] generics_0.0.2   htmltools_0.4.0  yaml_2.2.1      
[10] blob_1.2.1       rlang_0.4.6      pillar_1.4.4    
[13] withr_2.2.0      glue_1.4.1       DBI_1.1.0       
[16] dbplyr_1.4.4     modelr_0.1.8     readxl_1.3.1    
[19] lifecycle_0.2.0  munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.3.0    
[22] cellranger_1.1.0 rvest_0.3.5      psych_1.9.12.31 
[25] evaluate_0.14    knitr_1.28       parallel_4.0.0  
[28] fansi_0.4.1      broom_0.5.6      Rcpp_1.0.4.6    
[31] backports_1.1.7  scales_1.1.1     jsonlite_1.6.1  
[34] tmvnsim_1.0-2    fs_1.4.1         mnormt_2.0.0    
[37] hms_0.5.3        packrat_0.5.0    digest_0.6.25   
[40] stringi_1.4.6    bookdown_0.19    grid_4.0.0      
[43] cli_2.0.2        tools_4.0.0      magrittr_1.5    
[46] crayon_1.3.4     pkgconfig_2.0.3  ellipsis_0.3.1  
[49] xml2_1.3.2       reprex_0.3.0     lubridate_1.7.8 
[52] assertthat_0.2.1 rmarkdown_2.2    httr_1.4.1      
[55] rstudioapi_0.11  R6_2.4.1         nlme_3.1-147    
[58] compiler_4.0.0
```

---

Below is session info for a R session where it DID occur:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] janitor_2.0.1   gt_0.2.1        haven_2.3.1    
 [4] forcats_0.5.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.0    
 [7] purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.1.0    
[10] tibble_3.0.1    ggplot2_3.3.1   tidyverse_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] colorspace_1.4-1     ellipsis_0.3.1      
  [3] rio_0.5.16           snakecase_0.11.0    
  [5] htmlTable_1.13.3     base64enc_0.1-3     
  [7] fs_1.4.1             rstudioapi_0.11     
  [9] mice_3.9.0           rstan_2.19.3        
 [11] fansi_0.4.1          lubridate_1.7.8     
 [13] xml2_1.3.2           splines_4.0.0       
 [15] mnormt_2.0.0         knitr_1.28          
 [17] Formula_1.2-3        jsonlite_1.6.1      
 [19] packrat_0.5.0        broom_0.5.6         
 [21] cluster_2.1.0        dbplyr_1.4.4        
 [23] png_0.1-7            compiler_4.0.0      
 [25] httr_1.4.1           backports_1.1.7     
 [27] assertthat_0.2.1     Matrix_1.2-18       
 [29] survey_4.0           cli_2.0.2           
 [31] prettyunits_1.1.1    acepack_1.4.1       
 [33] htmltools_0.4.0      tools_4.0.0         
 [35] gtable_0.3.0         glue_1.4.1          
 [37] descr_1.1.4          Rcpp_1.0.4.6        
 [39] carData_3.0-4        cellranger_1.1.0    
 [41] vctrs_0.3.0          gdata_2.18.0        
 [43] nlme_3.1-147         psych_1.9.12.31     
 [45] xfun_0.14            ps_1.3.3            
 [47] openxlsx_4.1.5       rvest_0.3.5         
 [49] lifecycle_0.2.0      weights_1.0.1       
 [51] gtools_3.8.2         scales_1.1.1        
 [53] ENmisc_1.2-7         hms_0.5.3           
 [55] parallel_4.0.0       inline_0.3.15       
 [57] RColorBrewer_1.1-2   yaml_2.2.1          
 [59] curl_4.3             gridExtra_2.3       
 [61] loo_2.2.0            StanHeaders_2.21.0-3
 [63] rpart_4.1-15         latticeExtra_0.6-29 
 [65] stringi_1.4.6        plotrix_3.7-8       
 [67] checkmate_2.0.0      caTools_1.18.0      
 [69] pkgbuild_1.0.8       zip_2.0.4           
 [71] matrixStats_0.56.0   rlang_0.4.6         
 [73] pkgconfig_2.0.3      bitops_1.0-6        
 [75] evaluate_0.14        lattice_0.20-41     
 [77] htmlwidgets_1.5.1    tidyselect_1.1.0    
 [79] processx_3.4.2       plyr_1.8.6          
 [81] magrittr_1.5         bookdown_0.19       
 [83] R6_2.4.1             gplots_3.0.3        
 [85] generics_0.0.2       Hmisc_4.4-0         
 [87] DBI_1.1.0            pillar_1.4.4        
 [89] foreign_0.8-78       withr_2.2.0         
 [91] survival_3.1-12      abind_1.4-5         
 [93] nnet_7.3-13          modelr_0.1.8        
 [95] crayon_1.3.4         car_3.0-8           
 [97] KernSmooth_2.23-16   tmvnsim_1.0-2       
 [99] rmarkdown_2.2        jpeg_0.1-8.1        
[101] grid_4.0.0           readxl_1.3.1        
[103] data.table_1.12.8    blob_1.2.1          
[105] callr_3.4.3          reprex_0.3.0        
[107] digest_0.6.25        xtable_1.8-4        
[109] poliscidata_2.2.3    stats4_4.0.0        
[111] munsell_0.5.0        mitools_2.4
```

Comment: Your code is working for me with `dplyr` 1.0.0

Comment: Same here for me as for @akrun; code runs fine. Anthony, it would be helpful if you (1) [edit] your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()` so we know what software versions you're running and (2) make sure that this error occurs for you in a **fresh** R session. If not, then there's code you ran but did not show in your question that caused the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experienced the same issue. For me, adding `as.data.frame() %>%` solved it:

```
  psych::describe(mtcars$mpg) %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      mutate(variance = var(mtcars$mpg)) %>%
      select(n, mean, sd, variance, skew, kurtosis)

  # n     mean       sd variance     skew  kurtosis
  # 1 32 20.09062 6.026948  36.3241 0.610655 -0.372766
  
  sessionInfo()
  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
  Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
  Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
  dplyr_1.0.0            
  tidyverse_1.3.0        
  psych_1.9.12.31
```

Comment: This worked. Still can't figure out what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` 1.0.0, it is working

```
library(dplyr)
psych::describe(mtcars$mpg) %>% 
     mutate(variance = var(mtcars$mpg)) %>%
     select(n, mean, sd, variance, skew, kurtosis)
#   n  mean   sd variance skew kurtosis
#1 32 20.09 6.03    36.32 0.61    -0.37
```